# free modules or open source forums with Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore7.2, marketplace

Our client is asking to add forums functionalities to their site, they are using Sitecore 7.2 and the plan after developing the forums is to upgrade Sitecore to the latest release.

What I am looking for:

- Open source forum module that can be customized.
- Free module (no pricing).
- At least supports Sitecore 7.2 and prefer to be compatible with Sitecore 8.1
- Can be upgraded to Sitecore 8.1 if it's not compatible.

I found that Sitecore recommend some modules, but non of these support Sitecore new versions or Free.

Thank you

Comment: refer to Sitecore Community question: https://community.sitecore.net/general/f/16/t/1288